# Calculate if the train can pass over the bridge

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

The bridge's length and load-carrying capacity are known. Each of the train's wagons has a given length and weight. Program must determine whether the train can safely cross the bridge, i.e. whether the total weight of wagons that will simultaneously be on the bridge exceeds the bridge's carrying capacity.
To be safe, if any part of a wagon is on the bridge, we will count the entire weight of that wagon in computing the total weight at that moment.

**Input format:**

The first input line contains two integers: the length of the bridge and its carrying capacity.

The following input line(s) contain a sequence of pairs indicating the length and weight of each wagon in sequence. Each wagon's length and weight will always appear on the same line. Each input line will be at most 200 characters long.

**Output:**

If the train can safely cross the bridge, write the number -1. Otherwise, write the number of the first wagon that will cause the weight to exceed the bridge's carrying capacity. Wagons are numbered from 1.

*Sample input #1:*

> 10 100
>
> 10 90  10 10  9 80  1 10  9 10  9 80
>
> 5 10  5 10
>
> 1 10  1 10  1 10  1 10  1 40

*Output:*

> -1

*Sample input #2:*

> 7 20
>
> 3 4  3 5
>
> 3 5  3 7
>
> 3 7  3 7
>
> 3 6

*Output:*

> 4

**Some more examples:**

*Input:*

> 5 10
>
> 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 100 5 100 5 100

*Output:*

> 6

My code is

```
def bridge(p, k,  n):
    if p or n == 0:
        print(-1)
    else:
        wagon_length(lenght, wagon_lenght, p, n, k)
        
def wagon_length(lenght, wagon_lenght, p, n, k):
    lenght = lenght - wagon_lenght[n]
    wagon_lenght.remove(wagon_lenght[n])
    k = k+1
    if lenght > 0:
        n = n-1
        wagon_length(lenght, wagon_lenght, p, k, n)
       
    elif lenght <= 0:
        n = n-k
        wagon_mass(weight, wagon_weight, p, k, n)
        
              
def wagon_mass(weight, wagon_weight, p, k, n):
    res = sum(wagon_weight[-k:])
    weight = weight - res
    p = p - k
    wagon_weight.remove(wagon_weight[p])
    k = 0
    if weight < 0:
        print(p)
    if weight >= 0:
        bridge(p, k, n)        

a = input()
lines = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        break
text = '\n'.join(lines)
bbh = [int(t) for t in text.split()]
arr = [int(d) for d in a.split()]

k = 0
weight = arr[1]
lenght = arr[0]
wagon_weight = bbh[1::2]
wagon_lenght = bbh[0::2]
n = len(wagon_lenght)-1
p = len(wagon_weight)-1


bridge(p, k, n)
```

I tried to make it so that every time a wagon hits the bridge, we add one to the number k, which means the number of wagons that are currently on the bridge, and then just calculate the total weight of this number of wagons and subtract them from the maximum values ​​- if the weight is greater than or equal to zero, then these wagons have passed.

But the mistake of my code is that when operations are performed with list, instead of the last wagons (I go from the last to the first), it deletes the smallest values ​​and the code does not work as I intended

Comment: Could you add example input (and expected output) for which the problem arises and you get the wrong output?

Comment: Hey can you explain your inputs .. as per my understanding for input 2: max weight is 20 , max length of bridge is 7 , total wagons are 7 , wagon1:  ( 3,4), wagon2: (3,5), wagon3: (3,5),.....(3,7),(3,7),(3,7),(3,6) ?? If I am correct then how is it possible that bridge will be destroyed in this case? The weight of train on bridge will always be <=20 (I am considering the proportion weight of wagon ).

Comment: The bridge has length 7.

The first four wagons are

#1: length = 3, weight = 4
#2: length = 3, weight = 5
#3: length = 3, weight = 5
#4: length = 3, weight = 7
All of these have length 3, so 4 of them can be (at least partially) on the bridge at the same time. For example:

wagon #1: 0.5 meters
wagon #2: 3 meters (its entire length)
wagon #3: 3 meters (its entire length)
wagon #4: 0.5 meters
The sum of their weights is 21, which is too much, since the bridge's carrying capacity is 20.

Comment: If the wagon is partially on the bridge then how can you consider the full weight of wagon on the bridge ? ( 0.5*4+ 5 +5 + 0.5*7 = 15.5)

Comment: And what about first input? There should be 10 wagons but I see 13 pairs :o

Comment: @adarsh it's in question. `To be safe, if any part of a wagon is on the bridge, we will count the entire weight of that wagon in computing the total weight at that moment.`

Comment: @hopelessmixa what is your complexity expectation for this problem ?

Comment: @adarsh I was able to make the input, distribute it correctly according to the parameters, and the only problem that I cannot solve is to correctly make it so that he would consider whether the train could pass, and I have no new ideas, because my code is in the case of the second example does not work, but always returns -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the sequence of wagons into sequences of added and removed weights for each meter of the train's length.  The two sequences would be offset by the length of the bridge so that you can add them together and get the total load on the bridge every time the train moves by one meter.  The accumulate function from itertools can help with computing the total load at each meter:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def support(bridge,capacity,wagons):
    index  = [i for i,(wl,_) in enumerate(wagons,1) for _ in range(wl)]
    start  = accumulate(w for wl,ww in wagons 
                        for w in [ww]+[0]*(wl-1))
    end    = accumulate(-w for wl,ww in [(bridge,0)]+wagons 
                        for w in [0]*(wl-1)+[ww])
    load   = map(sum,zip(start,end))
    return next((index[m] for m,w in enumerate(load) if w>capacity),-1)
```

Output:

```
bridge   = 10
capacity = 100
wagons   = [(10,90),(10,10),(9,80),(1,10),(9,10),(9,80),(5,10),(5,10),
            (1,10),(1,10),(1,10),(1,10),(1,40)]
print(support(bridge,capacity,wagons)) # -1

bridge   = 7
capacity = 20
wagons   = [(3,4),(3,5),(3,5),(3,7),(3,7),(3,7),(3,6)]
print(support(bridge,capacity,wagons)) # 6

bridge   = 5
capacity = 10
wagons   = [(5,5),(5,5),(5,5),(5,5),(5,5),(5,100),(5,100),(5,100)]
print(support(bridge,capacity,wagons)) # 6
```

For example:

```
bridge   = 7
capacity = 20
wagons   = [(3,4),(3,5),(3,5),(3,7),(3,7),(3,7),(3,6)]
```

- `index` will contain the id of the wagon that is added on the bridge at the corresponding meter position
- `start` is the cumulative sum of wagon weights for wagons that are added on the bridge
- `end` is the cumulative sum of wagon weights for wagons that leave the bridge (negative)
- `load` is the actual load (added - leaving) on the bridge when the corresponding meter of the train reaches the bridge.
- After the last wagon is added on the bridge, is is not necessary to further check capacity as the load will only decrease thereafter

...

```
index 1 1 1 2 2 2  3  3  3  4  4  4  5  5  5   6   6   6   7   7   7
enter 4 0 0 5 0 0  5  0  0  7  0  0  7  0  0   7   0   0   6   0   0
(leaving)                   1  1  1  2  2  2   3   3   3   4   4   4 ...
leave 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0 -4  0  0 -5  0  0  -5   0   0  -7   0   0 ...
start 4 4 4 9 9 9 14 14 14 21 21 21 28 28 28  35  35  35  41  41  41
end   0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0 -4 -4 -4 -9 -9 -9 -14 -14 -14 -21 -21 -21 ...
load  4 4 4 9 9 9 14 14 14 17 17 17 19 19 19  21  21  21  20  20  20

                                               ^
                          Overload here _______|
```

**without libraries** *(same logic)*

```
def support(bridge,capacity,wagons):
    index = (i for i,(wl,_) in enumerate(wagons,1) for _ in range(wl))
    enter = (w for wl,ww in wagons for w in [ww]+[0]*(wl-1))
    leave = (w for wl,ww in [(bridge,0)]+wagons for w in [0]*(wl-1)+[ww])
    load = 0                                   # current load on bridge
    for i,more,less in zip(index,enter,leave): # examine each meter
        load += more-less                      # track total weigth
        if load>capacity: return i             # detect overload
    return -1
```

**memory efficient solution using a queue**

```
def support(bridge,capacity,wagons):
    onBridge = deque([(bridge,0)])         # wagons/weights on bridge
    load = 0                               # current load
    for i,(wl,ww) in enumerate(wagons,1):  
        load += ww                         # combined load (continuous)
        if load>capacity: return i         # check overload
        onBridge.append((wl,ww))           # add wagon on bridge
        while wl>0:                        # advance to end of wagon
            bl,bw = onBridge[0]            
            if wl>=bl:                     # reduce load for exiting
                load -= onBridge.popleft()[1]
            else:                          # reduce length for partial
                onBridge[0] = (bl-wl,bw)
            wl -= bl                       # up to new wagon's length
    return -1
```

Comment: But in the second case, the answer should be wagon 4, because

The bridge has length 7.

The first four wagons are

# 1: length = 3, weight = 4
# 2: length = 3, weight = 5
# 3: length = 3, weight = 5
# 4: length = 3, weight = 7
All of these have length 3, so 4 of them can be (at least partially) on the bridge at the same time. For example:

wagon # 1: 0.5 meters
wagon # 2: 3 meters (its entire length)
wagon # 3: 3 meters (its entire length)
wagon # 4: 0.5 meters
The sum of their weights is 21, which is too much, since the bridge's carrying capacity is 20.

Comment: Depends how you process the sub-meter transitions.  I used a discreet transition so the bridge would go from having wagons 1,2,2,2,3,3,3 to 2,2,2,3,3,3,4.  For a continuous transition (partial-1,2,2,2,3,3,3,partial-4), you just have to change `[(bridge,0)]` to `[(bridge+1,0)]` for the offsetting of ending weights.  (and that will return 4 for that test case)

Comment: Is there any way to use a queue to remember the number of cars on the bridge, to reduce memory consumption?

Comment: The second solution use generators for everything so te memory consumption is no greater than the length of the longest wagon.  Unless the wagons are unreasonably long, using a queue would not save much.

Comment: As I understand it, the program that tests the code actually has 4 tests, where it loads memory, and therefore I think that the most efficient way is to add a queue for the wagons that are already on the bridge.

Comment: Added an example of a queue based approach. It should be more memory efficient and probably faster as well because it advances by wagon lengths rather than meter-by-meter

Answer (score 0):

I haven't proved my solution. There might be some redundant code.

My code will return the index (0 based indexing) of 1st wagon which will cause the issue if you want the last just update the recursion:

- my code will return -1 if bridge is not destroyed.
- my code will return **(index,'s')** means the partial wagon at start will cause the destruction
- my code will return **(index,'e')** means the partial wagon at end will cause the destruction
- my code will return **(index,'f')** means the full wagon at start will cause the destruction

**My code :**

```
""" 
    - either wagon is fully on the bridge
    - or partially placed on the bridge
        - if partially place on the bridge:
            * wagon is at starting point
            * wagon is at last point
"""
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**8)

def move(wagonList, n , wagon , maxL, i, counter):
    weight = wagon[1]
    for j in range(i, n if counter > 0 else -1, counter):
        if((maxL - wagonList[j][0])  <= 0):
            weight += wagonList[j][1]
            break
        maxL -= wagonList[j][0]
        weight += wagonList[j][1]
    return weight
def moveCombo(wagonList, n , w , maxL, i,j):
    if(i < 0 or j >= n or maxL <= 0):
        return w
    #return max(moveCombo(wagonList, n , w+wagonList[j][1] , maxL-wagonList[j][0], i,j+1),moveCombo(wagonList, n , w+wagonList[i][1] , maxL-wagonList[i][0], i-1,j))    
    return max(moveCombo(wagonList, n , w+wagonList[j][1] , maxL-wagonList[j][0], i,j+1),
        max(moveCombo(wagonList, n , w+wagonList[i][1] , maxL-wagonList[i][0], i-1,j),
        moveCombo(wagonList, n , w+wagonList[j][1]+wagonList[i][1] , maxL-wagonList[j][0]-wagonList[i][0], i-1,j+1)
        ))
def Gwagon(wagonList, n , maxL, maxW):
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        wagon = wagonList[i]
        end = move(wagonList, n, wagon, maxL, i-1, -1) 
        start = move(wagonList, n, wagon, maxL, i+1, 1)
        full = moveCombo(wagonList, n , wagon[1] , maxL-wagon[0], i-1, i+1)
        if(start > maxW):
            res.append((i,'s'))
        if(end > maxW):
            res.append((i,'e'))
        if(full > maxW):
            res.append((i,'f'))
        if(res):
            break
    return res

def result(wagonList,n,maxL,maxW):
    res = Gwagon(wagonList,n,maxL,maxW)
    if(res):
        print(*res)
    else:
        print(-1)

wagonList=[(10,90),(10,10),(9,80),(1,10),(9,10),(9,80),(5,10),(5,10),(1,10),(1,10),(1,10),(1,10),(1,40)]
result(wagonList,13,10,100)
wagonList=[(3,4),(3,5),(3,5),(3,7),(3,7),(3,7),(3,6)]
result(wagonList,7,7,20)
```

**My Output:**

```
-1
(0, 's')
```

- our case 1 the bridge will not be destroyed so -1.
- our case 2 the bridge will be destroyed, 1st wagon will be wagon no-1 {4,5,5,7}. wagon -1 will be the starting point and bridge will be destroyed if wagon is partial on the bridge.

**New Code:**

```
""" 
    - either wagon is fully on the bridge
    - or partially placed on the bridge
        - if partially place on the bridge:
            * wagon is at starting point
            * wagon is at last point
"""
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**8)

def move(wagonList, n , wagon , maxL, i, counter):
    weight = wagon[1]
    obj = (weight,i-counter)
    for j in range(i, n if counter > 0 else -1, counter):
        if((maxL - wagonList[j][0])  <= 0):
            weight += wagonList[j][1]
            obj = (weight, j)
            break
        maxL -= wagonList[j][0]
        weight += wagonList[j][1]
    return obj
def moveCombo(wagonList, n , w , maxL, i,j, maxW):
    if(i < 0 or j >= n or maxL <= 0 or maxW < w):
        return (w,j-1)
        
    o1 = moveCombo(wagonList, n , w+wagonList[j][1] , maxL-wagonList[j][0], i,j+1, maxW)
    o2 = moveCombo(wagonList, n , w+wagonList[i][1] , maxL-wagonList[i][0], i-1,j ,maxW)
    o3 = moveCombo(wagonList, n , w+wagonList[j][1]+wagonList[i][1] , maxL-wagonList[j][0]-wagonList[i][0], i-1,j+1, maxW)
    res = (0,n+1)
    if(o1[0] > maxW):
        res = o1
    if(o2[0] > maxW):
        if(res[1] > o2[1]):
            res = o2
    if(o3[0] > maxW):
        if(res[1] > o3[1]):
            res = o3
    return res
    
def Gwagon(wagonList, n , maxL, maxW):
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        wagon = wagonList[i]
        end = move(wagonList, n, wagon, maxL, i-1, -1) 
        start = move(wagonList, n, wagon, maxL, i+1, 1)
        full = moveCombo(wagonList, n , wagon[1] , maxL-wagon[0], i-1, i+1, maxW)
        if(start[0] > maxW):
            res.append((start[1],'s'))
        if(end[0] > maxW):
            res.append((end[1],'e'))
        if(full[0] > maxW):
            res.append((full[1],'f'))
        if(res):
            break
    return res

def result(wagonList,n,maxL,maxW):
    res = Gwagon(wagonList,n,maxL,maxW)
    if(res):
        res.sort()
        print(res[0][0]+1)
    else:
        print(-1)

wagonList=[(10,90),(10,10),(9,80),(1,10),(9,10),(9,80),(5,10),(5,10),(1,10),(1,10),(1,10),(1,10),(1,40)]
result(wagonList,13,10,100)
wagonList=[(3,4),(3,5),(3,5),(3,7),(3,7),(3,7),(3,6)]
result(wagonList,7,7,20)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
-1
4
```

Comment: I would like to ask how can I display the number of the wagon that caused the bridge to collapse?

Comment: Code is qutie complicated, if you wist I could show you version with 10 lines of code @hopelessmixa, however hadn't time to look for a bug in your code.

Comment: @kosciej16 I will be very grateful if you can help me, it is interesting to look at the code, because I have no idea how to implement this

Comment: @hopelessmixa added the updated code

Comment: just try it and let me know. i guess recursion is redundant in it

Comment: @adarsh yes, the algorithm works, I'll just add to it so that the parameters can be used from the input, and then everything will be fine. Thanks a lot.
Only I don't know how to form pairs from the input, because I always wrote them down directly to the list

Comment: @hopelessmixa I hope you have tested on some cases before approval. (As I mentioned earlier I haven't proved it ).

Comment: @hopelessmixa should I delete the soln. if its's wrong?

Comment: @adarsh No, the code works fine, but it only had one problem: at the moments when tests specifically load memory, I could not make a code that could make input as a queue, so that there would be enough memory

Answer (score 0):

To avoid excessive memory use, you should not go for a solution where each unit of length is checked (like each meter if the unit if measure is meter). Instead go through the process of adding wagons at the end and removing them from the start.

As the weight of a wagon also counts when it is only touching the bridge, it will be useful to keep track of the the length and load with the following definitions:

- length: represents the total length of a range of wagons that fit *entirely* on the bridge
- load: represents the total weight of a range of wagons where the first and last wagon might not be completely on the bridge.

I would adapt the loading of data such that you don't need to zip to lists. Instead keep each wagon's length and weight together in a tuple. I would promote the use of named tuples here, since that improves the readability of the code.

As both the bridge and each wagon have a length and something that relates to weight, I would use the same named tuple class for both.

Here is the proposed code:

```
from collections import namedtuple

# Use named tuple to improve readability of the code
Item = namedtuple("Item", "length, weight")

def support(bridge, wagons):
    # Deal with boundary cases
    if not bridge.length or not wagons:
        return -1

    # initialise the total length of wagons that are completely on the bridge 
    length = 0
    # .... and the total weight of wagons that touch the bridge
    load = wagons[0].weight
    # Some more boundary cases
    if load > bridge.weight:
        return 1
    if len(wagons) == 1:
        return -1
    load += wagons[1].weight
    if load > bridge.weight:
        return 2

    # The following loop has this invariant:
    #    load = sum( wagon.weight for wagon in wagons[start-1:end+1] )
    #    length = sum ( wagon.length for wagon in wagons[start:end] )
    start = 1
    for end in range(1, len(wagons) - 1):
        # Remove first wagon(s) as long there is no room for the next wagon to 
        #    be partly on the bridge while also the first is still partly on the bridge
        while length + wagons[end].length >= bridge.length:
            load -= wagons[start - 1].weight
            length -= wagons[start].length
            start += 1
        # Now there is room for the next wagon...
        length += wagons[end].length
        load += wagons[end + 1].weight
        if load > bridge.weight:  # Exceeded the capacity of the bridge
            return end + 2
    
    return -1


# Helper functions to parse the input
def read_words_until_empty_line():
    line = input()
    while line:
        yield from line.split()
        line = input()

def words_to_items(words):
    it = map(int, words)
    for length in it:
        yield Item(length, next(it))

# Driver code
bridge, *wagons = words_to_items(read_words_until_empty_line())
print(support(bridge, wagons))
```

Comment: Yes, the code is really much better, thanks a lot, but he has a problem, when the length of the bridge is equal to the length of the wagon, then he thinks that it passes, although he should not (example: length of the bridge - 10, weight - 10, wagons - (10 10), (10 10), (10 10) and in this case, the bridge should collapse on the second wagon, but your code gives -1.
And I still don't know how, but apparently the tests load the code so much that the code did not pass two memory tests

Comment: Do you have a link to a full test suite, so I can test?

Comment: Also, I could not reproduce the example you give here. When I enter `10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10`, it outputs 2, to correctly indicate that the second wagon causes a collapse.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only give some additional examples that were given to me, but I cannot give a link to the tests, and I do not know how exactly they load memory, because only the result is returned

Comment: @tricon I also think that the test with 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 fails because there is a space between them, and when the program reads the input, it ignores the subsequent digits and just returns - 1 (it is probably better to make the end of the input EOFError)

Comment: Do you have a problem in adapting the code like that? See it run on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma704970915459839). It outputs 2. BTW, I based the input logic on what you had yourself as code, i.e. to read until there is an empty line in the input. Can you be explicit about the input format if it is not supposed to work like that? Is there no empty line at the end of the input?

Comment: If there is an empty line between the parameters of the bridge and the parameters of the wagons, the code will not work and will give -1 in all cases, so I think it would be better to do it via EOFError

Comment: My code does not care about line breaks, only the last one. But EOFError check is easy to add. Do you have a problem in doing so? I mean: surely your question is not about such a detail, but about the algorithm and memory and performance, right? Or do you really have a problem making it work with EOFError? Since I don't have access to the tester, I cannot know for sure if that is the issue you are dealing with.

Comment: No, there are no problems with EOFError check, just the same question is that in some situation, when the test loads the memory with numbers about 2000 characters long (as they wrote to me), then there is not enough memory

Comment: But let's first get back to the `10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10` case. Did you get it to work?

Comment: BTW: there should not be any problem in loading 2000 characters into memory, nor to have such input split into numbers and stored in memory, but it can be a problem for the solution code that Alain T provided, because it generates intermediate lists which are ***much*** larger.

Comment: Yes, I made an EOFError check, but now it never gives -1, but always gives the wagon number (for example, in the case of the first example, it gives 3)

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce this. The first example, even with EOFError check, gives me -1. Can you link (via URL) to the exact input file you are processing? Are you really reading from *standard* input, or from a file?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed everything and now EOFError check works as it should, code too. Now only two of all tests fail due to memory

Comment: How many numbers are in those failing tests?

Comment: The problem is that I don’t know how many numbers are in this test, all the information that is given to me is that tests like 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 and others that I gave load no more than 40%, but these two tests take more than 100%

Comment: "load" is usually not about memory usage, but CPU usage... are you sure there is a memory problem?

Comment: Yes, the processor usage is allocated in a separate line, and it does not load more than 40% anywhere and does an excellent job everywhere

Comment: This is too vague. I need to know the figures. I cannot imagine that the `wagons` list could not be allocated in memory (it is the only data structure that needs more than a constant amount of memory). You would need many *millions* of input numbers to get into a problem. Please provide what the constraints are, so I can reproduce any problem you might have.

Comment: I get a HTTP 404 on that link. Sorry, I am moving on. It is clear I cannot help you further with this. I get the impression your problems are more with specifics of the testing platform than with algorithm/memory.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the help, if there is time in the future, here are the results [link](https://ibb.co/gFYT4p9) . Unfortunately, this is just an image, since it does not allow access to the site.

Comment: Usually code challenges are accompanied by constraints: the limits that any input will have, in terms of number of inputs, and the range of the values in the input.

Comment: But more importantly: questions on Stack Overflow that concern undesired output, should have *all* information for us to *reproduce* the issue. If not available, we cannot really help you.