# How to make sequential data input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

I wanted to make a code that, when receiving data, process them in turn, and not just write them all into one list. Because in cases where numbers reach 2000 characters in length, the code consumes a lot of memory (allocated for this task)

As I understand it, these lines would be most efficient to use:

```
bridge_length, capacity = [int(w) for w in input().split()]
for line in sys.stdin:
    nums = [int(w) for w in line.split()]
```

But I don’t know how to add it to code correctly.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Item = namedtuple("Item", "length, weight")

def support(bridge, wagons):
    if not bridge.length or not wagons:
        return -1
    length = 0
    load = wagons[0].weight
    if load > bridge.weight:
        return 1
    if len(wagons) == 1:
        return -1
    load += wagons[1].weight
    if load > bridge.weight:
        return 2

    start = 1
    for end in range(1, len(wagons) - 1):
        while length + wagons[end].length >= bridge.length:
            load -= wagons[start - 1].weight
            length -= wagons[start].length
            start += 1
        length += wagons[end].length
        load += wagons[end + 1].weight
        if load > bridge.weight:  
            return end + 2
    
    return -1

def read_words_until_empty_line():
    while True:
        try:
            line = input()
        except:
            break
        yield from line.split()


def words_to_items(words):
    it = map(int, words)
    for length in it:
        yield Item(length, next(it))

bridge, *wagons = words_to_items(read_words_until_empty_line())
print(support(bridge, wagons))
```

Explanation: this code calculates whether the train can pass the bridge, which has a length, and the maximum weight that it can support. The first line of input just the same enters the parameters of the bridge, and the rest of the parameters are wagons. To be safe, if any part of a wagon is on the bridge, we will count the entire weight of that wagon in computing the total weight at that moment. If the train can safely cross the bridge, write the number -1. Otherwise, write the number of the first wagon that will cause the weight to exceed the bridge's carrying capacity. Wagons are numbered from 1.

**Input example:**

> 10 100
>
> 10 90  10 10  9 80  1 10  9 10  9 80
>
> 5 10  5 10
>
> 1 10  1 10  1 10  1 10  1 40

And this code does not require a lot of memory when the numbers are small, because it simply writes them all into one list, and then it works with them, but I would like to know if there is a way to make the data enter only when it is needed process, and then just delete, so as not to load memory

Comment: *"I wanted to make a code that, when receiving data, process them in turn, and not just write them all into one list."*:  the reason for the huge memory usage is not caused by putting the input in lists. It is caused by the definition of `enter` and `leave`. As this is a follow up on your original question, and you deleted your second question, I will prepare an answer to your first question, even though you marked as accepted the answer with this memory-unfriendly answer.

Comment: @hopelessmixa  : I would suggest going with batch process would be better

Comment: I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70497091/5459839) to your original question that also answers this one.